# get filenames in a directory without extension - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the filenames in a directory without getting the extension. With my current code -

```
import os

path = '/Users/vivek/Desktop/buffer/xmlTest/' 
files = os.listdir(path) 
print (files)
```

I end up with an output like so:

```
['img_8111.jpg', 'img_8120.jpg', 'img_8127.jpg', 'img_8128.jpg', 'img_8129.jpg', 'img_8130.jpg']
```

However I want the output to look more like so:

```
['img_8111', 'img_8120', 'img_8127', 'img_8128', 'img_8129', 'img_8130']
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: ... By slicing them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `os`'s splitext.

```
import os

path = '/Users/vivek/Desktop/buffer/xmlTest/' 
files = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(path)]
print (files)
```

Just a heads up: `basename` won't work for this.  `basename` doesn't remove the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options

```
import os
print(os.path.splitext("path_to_file")[0])
```

Or

```
from os.path import basename
print(basename("/a/b/c.txt"))
```

Comment: `basename("/a/b/c.txt")` returns c.txt, WITH extension.